# Randomization involving buttons (VB)

Tags: vb.net, random

Using VB I can create and access a random "cell" in an array like so

```
Dim array(5) as array
Dim r as new random
r.next(0,5)
```

array(r) will then access a random "cell" based upon r's value.

Is there a way to say something like button(r) to directly randomize which button is chosen instead of having to use a random and If's like so?

```
r.next(0,5)
If r = 1 then
button1 ...
elseif r = 2
button 2 ...
end if
```

Comment: What version vb are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Using an array of Button is the superior solution.  But you can do it cheap by choosing the button names carefully:

```
Dim btn as Button = DirectCast(Me.Controls("Button" + r.Next(6).ToString()), Button)
```

Note that I used 6.  arrButtons(5) contains 6 elements at indices 0 through 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of buttons, like this:

```
'In your class
Dim buttons() As Button
Dim rand as New Random()
Public Sub New() 
    InitializeComponent()
    buttons = New Button() { Button1, Button2, ... }
End Sub

'Somewhere else:
Dim randomButton As Button = buttons(rand.Next(buttons.Length))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of buttons, sure you can.

Looking at your codes, seems like you are refering to VB.NET.

```
Dim r as New Random(someSeed)
Dim arrButtons(5) As Button
'assign the buttons to the array
'.....
Dim chosenButton As Button = Buttons(r.Next(0,arrButtons.Length))
```